# Obtener el Id de registro almacenado y guardar en otra tabla

Tags: php, laravel, livewire

Estoy creando un registro y necesito almacenar este id del registro que se creo recien en otra tabla, estoy intentando obtener dicho id y almacenarlo pero no me resulta, actualmente tengo este codigo.

```
public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate();
        
        $order = new Order;
        $order->id_state_id = $this->id_state;
        $order->id_customer_id = $this->id_customer;  
        $order->address = $this->order->address;
        $order->reference = $this->order->reference;
        $order->date = $this->order->date;

        //dd($order);

        $order->save();

        $createOrderSpecification = OrderSpecification::create(
            ['id_specification_id' => $this->specification],
            ['id_order_id' => $order->getKey()],
        );
     
        return redirect()->route('admin.orders.edit', $order->id);
        Session::flash('message', $id.' has been approved',array('timeout' => 3000), 'error');        
    }
```

Aqui en esta parte necesito pasar el id de la orden creada al `id_order_id`, intente con el `getKey()`, tambien con `$oder->id` pero no me funcionan.

```
$createOrderSpecification = OrderSpecification::create(
            ['id_specification_id' => $this->specification],
            ['id_order_id' => $order->getKey()],
        );
```

Comment: Estas obteniendo el `$oder->id` despues del save, porque sino en la posicion del dd aun no hay un registro hecho.

Comment: También podrías definir la relación en el modelo, y dejar que Eloquent se ocupe de la llave foránea